# Adding features to an SQL Server 2008 standard with SP1

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have MS SQL Server 2008 with SP1 installed.
I want to add the Full text feature to the installation.
Do I need to run the SP1 update again after I add this feature?
If I do try to run it (SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x64-ENU) it fails with this error:
"There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer".

Should I uninstall SP1 and re-install? Doesnt make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text search is a feature of the Database Engine, and as such is not a main component of SQL Server 2008, but only a sub-feature; you don't need to apply the service pack to it, because it has already been applied to that Database Engine instance.

If you were f.e. installing Analysis Services on a server where those weren't already installed, you would have then needed to apply SP1 to *them*.